# problem accessing USB drive on nfs server from a client

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, mount, nfs

So my server is at 192.168.0.15

the client is at 192.168.0.17

(Both machines have a user called 'work')

On the server, my USB HDD auto mounts as /media/work/EXT4-4TB

I'd like to access this from the nfs client, so, on the server my /etc/exports contains:

/media/work/EXT4-4TB  192.168.0.17(rw,sync,no_root_squash)

To start the nfs server I run:

$ sudo systemctl start nfs-kernel-server.service

On the client I have an empty directory set up at /home/work/archive/

But when I try and access the share with:

$ sudo mount 192.168.0.15:/home/work/EXT4-4TB /home/work/archive/

I get:

mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.15:/home/work/EXT4-4TB

I can access other nfs shared directories on this server, but the difference seems to be that this one is over USB.

I'm thinking it's something to do with the auto-mount or permissions but am out of ideas at this point on how to fix the problem.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed your paths are wrong after posting my response below. You are exporting `/media/work/EXT4-4TB` but on your client you are trying to mount `/home/work/EXT4-4TB`. You can mount the USB in `fstab` into `/home/work`using step #2 in my response below. Try using `sudo mount 192.168.0.15:/media/work/EXT4-4TB` on the client as well if you want to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: Embarrassing. That was the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

1. `sudo blkid` to get the UUID of the USB drive
2. Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to make the drive mount the same way every time, use the UUID instead of the /dev/sdX path, mount it in `/mnt` instead of the temporary `/media` folder
3. Add the new mount path to your `/etc/exports`
4. `sudo exportfs -ra` to load the new NFS settings

Comment: Although, my typo was to blame, this looks like a better way to deal with this. I will mark the question as answered. Thank you for the help.